# Viewing http requests made by flash players

Tags: flash, http, networking, request

I want to view the http requests that are made by the flash plugin while seeing a video. I am using google Chrome on Mac OSx.

I can not see the video getting downloaded in the network panel neither am I able to see it in fiddler.

Please Help!

Comment: Check if this can be of any help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153593/firebug-like-debug-tool-for-flash-applications-that-run-in-a-browser

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. Why does the chrome debugger not show network requests btw?

Comment: Click on the `Network` tab in Chrome Console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open Tools - Developer Tools. Choose "Network" tab. Here is it: you can view any http requests, including requests from/to swf.

Comment: what about rtmp requests?

Comment: I don't know, if there are special tools for rtmp monitoring, but you can use Wireshark. It's a universal sniffer, and it has tools for rtmp too.

Comment: I have wireshark. Can you give an example filter?

Answer (score 3):

This is now fixed in recent versions of Chrome. They come with the PPAPI version of the Flash plugin, which passes through DevTools.

Comment: By "fixed" do you mean devtools can't see it?  Because right now some flash-based games no longer show up on the network tab of chrome's developer tools.  Others do.